# logback configuration doesn't work for spring

Tags: java, spring, slf4j, logback, appender

I have the following the `logback.xml file`

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="my.package">
    <level value="TRACE"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.web">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
</logger>

<root>
    <priority value="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

When I run the application, in console I see messages which was invoked like this:

```
LOGGER.error("error ");
```

from classes inside `my.package`
I don't see messages from spring.

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Spring logs to Apache Commons Logging. To switch it to logback exclude Commons Logging

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

and add bridge to Logback

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I have the parent child relation between my pom.xml. Where better to write exclusions ?

Answer (score 1):

Spring uses `commons-logging`, so you need to use the `jcl-over-slf4j` bridge to make spring think it's using jcl.

You'll need to exclude `commons-logging` from the spring dependencies in your pom, and include the `jcl-over-slf4j`.

More information: [Bridging Legacy APIs](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html)

Comment: I have the parent child relation between my pom.xml. Where better to write exclusions ?